# Oracle Order by - Function Based (dense_rank)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table that has the following 4 columns with some example data

```
Aisle | Rack | Level | Position
  1        1       1         1
  1        2       1         2
  2        1       1         1
  2        2       1         1
  2        3       1         1
  3        1       1         1
  3        2       1         1
```

I wish to write a single query that can Sort records using the following

- First by Aisle (Ascending)
- Then by Rack (Ascending for one Aisle and Descending for the next and
  so on. . .This is the part that I can't seem to figure out if it can
  be achieved in Oracle)
- Then by Level (Ascending)
- Then by Position (Ascending)

So the resulting ordered rows will be as follows

```
 Aisle | Rack | Level | Position
  1        1       1         1
  1        2       1         2
  2        3       1         1
  2        2       1         1
  2        1       1         1
  3        1       1         1
  3        2       1         1
```

We worked out the following Order by Clause

```
order by aisle,
      (case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by aisle), 2) = 1 then rack else - rack
       end),
      level,
      position
```

But, I am getting an error **"ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER"** when I execute the query. The columns are all VARCHAR2 type.

What could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the columns are `varchar2()`, then unary minus isn't going to work so well.

How about this instead?

```
order by aisle,
      (case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by aisle), 2) = 1 then rack end) asc,
      (case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by aisle), 2) = 0 then rack end) desc,
      level,
      position
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by `rack`, ascending/descending, but if you leave `rack` as `varchar2` then 9 will come before 10 in ascending order (because you are ordering alphabetically, not numerically, and in the alphabetical order the character 1 comes before 9).

Unless that is the intended behavior (it may be, but it would be unusual), it would be best to wrap all occurrences of `rack` within `to_number()`, that is, order by `to_number(rack)` - whether in your original attempt (which should now work, with this modification) or in Gordon's solution - which may suffer from the "alphabetical ordering" issue if you don't use `to_number()`.